# Select2 with closeOnSelect = false stops highlight of first item and issue with arrow key navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

If at all possible i'm NOT ready for version 4+. There is too much surrounding work required and the obvious issue that features developed in 3.5.4 will break when moving to 4+.

Here is the bug:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2783

Here is an updated jsFiddle using version 3.5.4
http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcc/667/

```
<input type="hidden" style="width:100%">

<script>
    var data = [{
        id: 1,
        text: "A"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "B"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "C"
    }];
    $('input').select2({
        multiple: true,
        data: data,
        closeOnSelect : false
    });
</script>
```

You will notice that when clicking in the select2 field that the first item does not highlight. This stops a user from then using the arrow key to navigate. Removing this parameter works but the field closes prematurely. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I updated line 3351 to:

```
if (this.highlight() == -1 && noHighlightUpdate !== false){
    self.highlight(0);
}
```